# Inherit and add value to multi-value CSS property?

Tags: css, inheritance

As we all know, some CSS properties can have multiple values simultaneously. A good example is CSS3's `box-shadow`.

However, sometimes it may be desirable for a class or ID to add to these values. For example, if I have an element with an inset `box-shadow` value, I may want to add an outer glow to the box with an `.active` class. Unfortunately, this overwrites the previous value.

Is it possible to inherit a value and simultaneously add to it? Below is a non-working example of what I am hoping can be accomplished. Notice how the end-result does not glow.

```css
div {
  background-color: #09F;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 10px #FFF inset, -3px -3px 10px #00F inset;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

div.active {
  box-shadow: inherit, 0 0 10px #FF0;
}
```

```html
<div class="active"></div>
```

Comment: Nope...not possible. `inherit` means "be the same"...it can't be the same **and** different at the same time.